# App Bundle crashes with Admob GDPR Message Implementation but not in APK or DEBUG

Tags: android, admob, android-app-bundle, gdprconsentform

I have implemented the GDPR Mwssage and made a App Bundle Release after the update is rolled out i see the app started crashing on launch without any trace of whats wrong , but as i knew the only code i added in the update was the GDPR message code so the i tried to remove the code and add the .aab in Internal app sharing and tested throughly

after adding and removing the GDPR messgae code in the Internal App Sharing im 90% sure that this is the code that is crashing my app in the App Bundle Install but dont undertand what is the issue with it and why only with .aab and dosent crash on signed apk

Here is the code

```
     ConsentRequestParameters params = new ConsentRequestParameters
                .Builder()
                .setTagForUnderAgeOfConsent(false)
                .build();

   consentInformation = UserMessagingPlatform.getConsentInformation(this);
            consentInformation.requestConsentInfoUpdate(
                    this,
                    params,
                    new ConsentInformation.OnConsentInfoUpdateSuccessListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onConsentInfoUpdateSuccess() {
                            // The consent information state was updated.
                            // You are now ready to check if a form is available.
                            if (consentInformation.isConsentFormAvailable()) {

                                loadForm();
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new ConsentInformation.OnConsentInfoUpdateFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onConsentInfoUpdateFailure(FormError formError) {
                            // Handle the error.
                        }
                    });

public void loadForm() {
        // Loads a consent form. Must be called on the main thread.
        UserMessagingPlatform.loadConsentForm(
                this,
                new UserMessagingPlatform.OnConsentFormLoadSuccessListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConsentFormLoadSuccess(ConsentForm consentForm) {
                        MainActivity.this.consentForm = consentForm;
                        if (consentInformation.getConsentStatus() == ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.REQUIRED) {
                            consentForm.show(
                                    MainActivity.this,
                                    new ConsentForm.OnConsentFormDismissedListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onConsentFormDismissed(@Nullable FormError formError) {
                                            if (consentInformation.getConsentStatus() == ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.OBTAINED) {
                                                // App can start requesting ads.

                                            }

                                            // Handle dismissal by reloading form.
                                            loadForm();
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                    }
                },
                new UserMessagingPlatform.OnConsentFormLoadFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConsentFormLoadFailure(FormError formError) {
                        // Handle Error.
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

also just for information im also getting this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.tools.lint.client.api.Vendor
```

in the Build , i tried to inspect code from anaylze> inspect code but didnt found any error

sorry but at this moment i dont have ant adb logcats available

Comment: Show the logs of the crash

Comment: how can i get the logs ? in adb ? becuase when i use this 

'adb -s <deviuce id>logcat -s <package name>'

im getting just this 

--------- beginning of system
--------- beginning of crash
--------- beginning of main

Comment: Should show up in the logs tab in android studio itself https://www.papertrail.com/solution/tips/how-to-diagnose-app-issues-using-crash-logs/